# Equivalent Subquery for a Join

Tags: sql, sql-server, relational-database

I am looking for an answer which is actually

***Is It possible to rewrite every Join to equivalent Subquery***
I know that Subquery columns can not be selected outer query.
I run a query in sql server which is

```
  select DISTINct A.*,B.ParentProductCategoryID from [SalesLT].[Product] as 
  A inner join [SalesLT].[ProductCategory] as B on 
  A.ProductCategoryID=B.ProductCategoryID

 select A.*
  from [SalesLT].[Product] as A
  where EXISTS(select B.ParentProductCategoryID  from [SalesLT].
 [ProductCategory] as B where A.ProductCategoryID=B.ProductCategoryID)
```

Both of these query giving me output 293 rows which I expected.
Now Problem is How do I select [SalesLT].[ProductCategory] the column in the 2nd case?

Do I need to co-relate this subquery in the select clause to get this column to be shown in output?

Answer (score 1):

> Is It possible to rewrite every Join to equivalent Subquery

No, because joins can 1) remove rows or 2) multiply rows

ex 1)

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (num int)
CREATE TABLE t2 (num int)

INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (1), (2), (3)
INSERT INTO t2 VALUES (2) ,(3)

SELECT * FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.num = t2.num
```

Gives output

```
t1num   t2num
2       2
3       3
```

The row containing value 1 from t1 was removed. This does not happen in a subquery.

ex 2)

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (num int)
CREATE TABLE t2 (num int)

INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (1), (2), (3)
INSERT INTO t2 VALUES (2) ,(3), (3), (3), (3)
SELECT t1.num AS t1num, t2.num as t2num FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.num = t2.num
```

Gives output

```
t1num   t2num
2       2
3       3
3       3
3       3
3       3
```

A subquery would not change the number of rows in the table being queried.

---

In your example, you do an exists... this is not going to return the value from the 2nd table.

This is how I would subquery:

```
select A.*
      ,(SELECT B.ParentProductCategoryID
          FROM [SalesLT].[ProductCategory] B
         WHERE B.ProductCategoryID = A.ProductCategoryID) AS [2nd table ProductCategoryID]
  from [SalesLT].[Product] as A
```

Comment: I asked this this question as i have heard from the professor that Join and subquery we can use interchangeably.But Your answer is showing me different thing as you said they are not equally powerful

Comment: They can be used interchangably but only in one case, I think.  A LEFT JOIN will give the same answer if you are joining on primary key or `DISTINCT` value.  That is because the joining condition is distinct for LEFT JOIN- so it will not multiply rows; and in either case both return NULL if they do not match on joining conditions.

Comment: If I cant select column from the other table ,its hard for me to say they can be used interchangeably.Isn't it ?

Comment: I've edited the answer to include an example of a subquery that selects from the other table.

Comment: What if I want more than 5 columns from table 2 ? the same kind of lines I need to write for each column to get selected right ?

Comment: That's right. A subquery in the select statement only returns one value.

Answer (score 0):

You might use

```
select A.*, 
(
   select B.ParentProductCategoryID  
   from [SalesLT].[ProductCategory] as B 
   where A.ProductCategoryID=B.ProductCategoryID
) ParentProductCategoryID  
from [SalesLT].[Product] as A
where EXISTS(select 1 
   from [SalesLT].[ProductCategory] as B 
   where A.ProductCategoryID=B.ProductCategoryID)
```

however, I find the `JOIN` version much more intuitive.

There is no way for you to use any data from the `EXISTS` subquery in the outer query. The only purpose of the subquery is to evaluate whether the `EXISTS` is true or false for each product.

Comment: Then for each column of table 2 if I need to get them in reult I need to do Like (
   select B.ParentProductCategoryID  
   from [SalesLT].[ProductCategory] as B 
   where A.ProductCategoryID=B.ProductCategoryID
) ParentProductCategoryID